# There is a collection in mongodb. Almost all fields need to be queried or sorted. How to design and optimize it?

Tags: mongodb, optimization

For example, in a collection, there are 20 fields, and there may be 15-16 to participate in the query. For example, the timestamp class needs to be sorted.

How to design this kind of problem.

---

As a digression, there were trading platforms for playing online games before. There were dozens of conditions for query and screening. How did they do it?

---

Thank you for your help

Comment: Create indexes for the most frequently queried fields and fields which have high cardinality, i.e. many different values in relation to the total number of documents.

Comment: See wildcard indexes.